# Customer wants a bad navigation schema

Tags: navigation, ux-designer

In the schema, there is no hierarchical level defined. It pretty much looks like something that hasn't been thought out. You could call it a "filter by" graph. In other words, the navigation is really a set of *filter by* parameters divided in several screens:

```
Init --> filter 1 --> filter 2 --> filter 3 --> filter 4 --> user list
```

The UX team did develop a navigation schema based on the customer's schema. We meet up with the customer, explained the reasons that made the developed schema could be easier to learn by users and brought more benefits.

```
Init --> user list (options: filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4)
```

After explaining it to the customer, he didn't seem like totally closed to the idea, but also didn't seem willingly to let us guide him (maybe we messed up when explaining it). That being said, the customer has trusted us in every other aspect of the developmet that we has recommended so far.

The example I provided in this question isn't the actual schema. The bad schema had about 10+ hierarchy levels because it nests filters from 2 actual entities. Something like

```
Init --> filter A 1 --> filter A 2 --> filter A 3 --> schools
Init --> filter B 1 --> filter B 2 --> filter B 3 --> filter B3 --> users --> (and here it repeats the whole hierarchy above like this:) --> filter A 1 --> filter A 2 --> filter A 3 --> schools
```

Aside the fact that it is indeed the customer who decides what he wants, I feel (and that may be wrong) that as an UX experienced team, we should guide him into something that will actually work.  How should I approach this?

Comment: If you have time and resources...with two prototypes. If, after trying, he still wants the other version then...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an UX question, this looks more like a customer relationship question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be an UX question, more like a customer relationship question

Comment: Then don't let the customer design your product. Understand the underlying need and then solve their problem. Don't let them dictate the navigation schema.

Comment: Do you want us to evaluate whether your design is better, or just tell you how to make a case to the customer?  If the former, then the question is on topic, but you need to provide more information about the design issue.  We don't really have enough to evaluate the design.

Comment: I realize my problem is more of how to communicate to the customer that his navigation design is bad,  and that is probably offtopic, if so I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to your client and say:

> Hey, we did some user testing and with our schema 10 users completed 5 different tasks in **35% of the time** they did with the existing schema. We also did some within-group testing and guess what - they hated your schema, they said it is "**stupid**", "**messed-up**", and "**downright unusable**".

But saying that would make you a liar.

So perhaps do some **user testing** and report back the truth?

Comment: "Helping someone is the same thing as messing with them." (From the movie, *The Hotel New Hampshire*)